# How to rollback the changed data in a WPF Child Window when cancel button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Ok let's say we have a `Parent Window` bound to a `DataContext` now assume we fire a `Child Window` and set its data context to that of the parent window. Now the items in the child window are bound to the data context in `TwoWay` mode. When the user changes something in this child window the data in the source viewmodel will be updated. But what if the user closes the window with `DialogResult == false`? How to rollback the data to its original?

For now I'm binding the data in `OneWay` mode and applying the changes only when the `DialogResult == true`. But I guess there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: If you define a VM property or command corresponging to your confirmation event, then you could move all the `OnPropertyChanged` from the setters of the items to that point.

Comment: @MachineLearning Can you please give me an example for this. This seems like a clean solution but I need some implementation example to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### IEditableObject

In the same way that WPF can use `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` you can also use the interface [`System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).  This interface has the following useful methods:

- [`BeginEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`EndEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx) - not really required for our use
- [`CancelEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.canceledit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Prior to displaying your window, call `BeginEdit()` on your datacontext.  Now any changes reflect via the usual `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the parent receives updates as usual.

If the user cancels, then call `CancelEdit()` at which point your viewmodel should rollback the changes.  The free set of steak knives is that your parent window is informed of the rollback via `INotifyPropertyChanged` thus "reverting" the parent window too.

Otherwise call `EndEdit()` which honestly isn't required as the changes are done already.

Obviously you would need to remember somehow the prior values so that you can revert any changes.

### IRevertibleChangeTracking

I've just read about `System.ComponentModel.IRevertibleChangeTracking` which offers the methods `AcceptChanges()` and `RejectChanges()`.  Though arguably this is the interface to use for *accepting* and *rolling back changes*, it's not entirely clear whether changes made in the interim should be broadcast in the WPF scenario.  Perhaps someone can help me here.

[Tell me more...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967189/585968)

Comment: Thanks MickyD, so in my Viewmodel I will need to keep the original data for all the properties as separate properties/fields?

Comment: Thank you. This is working well. Although one needs to keep track of all the properties in the viewmodel to make a backup but it is still easier than other methods.

Comment: @Vahid You're welcome good sir.  There might be some trick.  Maybe have a loop to reflect over all your `public` properties then later reflect again to see what's changed?

Comment: I just noticed a weird thing. When I use two radio buttons, with the `IsChecked` bound to a property with converter, and I cancel the first time, it works. The next time I cancel it also works. The third time when I change it is locked on one radio button and won't change!

Comment: This is odd, it is not because of the `BeginEdit()` methods. I'll post it as another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434625/odd-behavior-when-trying-to-change-a-bound-radiobutton-in-wpf

Comment: @Vahid Interesting.  Feel free to post that as a _new question_

Comment: Thanks MickyD, I did. It seems it was because of the Converter I used.

Comment: Hi, can you please see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544631/datagrid-causes-beginedit-method-to-run-twice

Comment: @Vahid very good. For a datagrid I too recommend the other post but otherwise I stand by my solution. Glad you got it going

Answer (score 1):

Change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the binding to be explicit and call the `UpdateSource` method only when the OK button is clicked.

[UpdateSourceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mvarta I was just reading about this method but I couldn't find any good code example. How can I do it for example for two radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can bind the confirmed values as one-way, readonly in the main view and the uncommitted ones to the dialog text boxes.

```
ViewModel
    class MyVM : MVVM.ViewModel.ViewModelBase
    {
        private string name1;
        public string Name1
        {
            get { return name1; }
            set {
                name1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Name1);
            }
        }
        string name1Conf;
        public string Name1Conf
        {
            get { return name1Conf; }
        }
        private string name2;
        public string Name2
        {
            get { return name2; }
            set
            {
                name2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Name2);
            }
        }
        string name2Conf;
        public string Name2Conf
        {
            get { return name2Conf; }
        }

        private bool commitMe;

        public bool CommitMe
        {
            get { return commitMe; }
            set {
                commitMe = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => CommitMe);
                if (commitMe)
                {
                    DoCommit();
                } 
            }
        }

        private void DoCommit()
        {
            name1Conf = name1;
            name2Conf = name2;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Name1Conf);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Name2Conf);
        }
    }
```

CodeBehind

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var win2 = new WPFDialog();
    win2.DataContext = myVM;
    var res = win2.ShowDialog();
    myVM.CommitMe = res == true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative method.