# DataGrid causes BeginEdit() method to run twice

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have implemented `IEditableObject` for my **ViewModel** and the below controls are bound to it.

Now when the first time I fire up the `Window` containing these controls, the `BeginEdit()` method runs and backs up the variables.

**My problem is this:** When I start editing the `DataGrid` again the `BeginEdit()` method runs and saves the changes to my already backed up variables! This ruins the purpose of the `BeginEdit()` and `CancelEdit()`. Now if I choose to cancel the Window, I won't have the original data. How can I prevent this?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CoatingFactors}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CoatingFactor}">
</ComboBox>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomCFactors}"                      
  ....
</DataGrid>
```

Here is how I have implemented the `BeginEdit()` and `CancelEdit()` methods:

```
private List<CustomCFactorItem> customCFactors_ORIGINAL;
private double coatingFactor_ORIGINAL;


public void BeginEdit()
{
    customCFactors_ORIGINAL = customCFactors.ConvertAll(o => o.Clone()).ToList();
    coatingFactor_ORIGINAL = coatingFactor;
}

public void CancelEdit()
{
    customCFactors = customCFactors_ORIGINAL.ConvertAll(o => o.Clone()).ToList();
    coatingFactor = coatingFactor_ORIGINAL;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For now, I'm using a little hack like this:

```
    private List<CustomCFactorItem> customCFactors_ORIGINAL;
    private double coatingFactor_ORIGINAL;

    private int editNum = 0;

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        if (editNum > 0) return;

        editNum++;

        customCFactors_ORIGINAL = customCFactors.ConvertAll(o => o.Clone());
        coatingFactor_ORIGINAL = coatingFactor;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        editNum = 0;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        editNum = 0;

        customCFactors = customCFactors_ORIGINAL.ConvertAll(o => o.Clone());
        coatingFactor = coatingFactor_ORIGINAL;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to fight with the WPF `DataGrid` control at the UI layer. Without writing your own controls designed to suit your own purposes, you simply won't win that fight. There will always be another Microsoft "gotcha" to deal with. I recommend implementing the desired behaviour from the safe-haven of an `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CustomCFactors.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (CustomCFactorItem item in e.NewItems)
                        item.PropertyChanged += BackupLogicEventHandler;
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (CustomCFactorItem item in e.OldItems)
                        item.PropertyChanged -= BackupLogicEventHandler;
                    break;
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            CustomCFactors.Add(new CustomCFactorItem("one", "two", "three"));
        }
        ExecuteBackupLogic();

    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomCFactorItem> CustomCFactors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomCFactorItem>();

    public void BackupLogicEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
        ExecuteBackupLogic();
    }
    public void ExecuteBackupLogic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("changed");
    }
}
```

And Here's a sample of what `CustomCFactorItem` might look like

```
public class CustomCFactorItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _field1 = "";
        public string Field1
        {
            get
            {
                return _field1;
            }
            set
            {
                _field1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Field1");
            }
        }
        private string _field2 = "";
        public string Field2
        {
            get
            {
                return _field2;
            }
            set
            {
                _field2 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Field2");
            }
        }
        private string _field3 = "";
        public string Field3
        {
            get
            {
                return _field3;
            }
            set
            {
                _field3 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Field1");
            }
        }
        public CustomCFactorItem() { }
        public CustomCFactorItem(string field1, string field2, string field3)
        {
            this.Field1 = field1;
            this.Field2 = field2;
            this.Field3 = field3;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

And this is a simple View that binds the collection to `DataGrid`. Notice that output is written to the console each time an edit is made.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CustomCFactors}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field 1" Binding="{Binding Field1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field 2" Binding="{Binding Field2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field 3" Binding="{Binding Field3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Jace, I'm not adding or removing anything from my Collection, only simple editing. How do I implement it?

Comment: I made a mistake in the syntax, but I've updated the code now.

Comment: You can find many tutorials online about `MVVM` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The add and remove logic in this example will apply to the items when you first load the collection. So, all you have to do is bind to the `ObservableCollection` object, and fill in `ExecuteBackupLogic` to determine what to do when any item in your collection is modified.

Comment: But Jace, this code doesn't prevent the DataGrid from running the BeginEdit method in the code-behind.

Comment: Ah, but it doesn't need to. You're calling `ExecuteBackupLogic` in the `ViewModel` constructor, so you have the original copy of the data before anything is even bound to the view. Next, you're wiring up a change-capture system that allows you to execute any logic you want each time a user edits the data from your `DataGrid`. You've effectively bypassed the need to struggle with the UI events at all. I've updated my answer to provide a more flushed out example that you can experiment with. Just give it a try, you'll never go back.

Comment: Also, I'm using c# 6.0, so depending on your environment, you might have to instantiate the `ObservableCollection` from the `ViewModel` constructor. Just a head's up.

Comment: Thank you so much. So you mean that I should ditch `BeginEdit` and not use it for back up purposes in the first place right? That totally makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. Implementing BLL code from the view is absolutely painful. You're essentially fishing through the UI routing strategy hoping you'll catch everything you need by subscribing to events that already have a stand-alone function that has nothing to do with your `ViewModel`. By implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you have the freedom to execute your logic on your time so you can decide when and how your custom event-handler is invoked.

Comment: Thanks very much for the valuable insights.